# Linux RPMBUILD SPEC, how to Install to custom location /usr/local/file1 not always /usr dirctory

Tags: linux, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I'm having problem for RPM to be installed to `/usr/local/file1`, it always installs to `/usr/local/file1/usr`.   I even used `./configure --prefix /usr/local/file1` and it still installed to `/usr/local/file1/usr directory`.

I wonder if anyone can help to see where in my spec is wrong.

```
%setup -q -n file1-%{version}

%build
./autogen.sh
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/file1

%install
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/usr/local/file1
mkdir -p $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/usr/local/file1
make install DESTDIR=$RPM_BUILD_ROOT/usr/local/file1

%clean
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/usr/local/file1

%files
%defattr(-,root,root,-)
/usr/local/file1/
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `make install` step shouldn’t repeat the path:

```
make install DESTDIR=$RPM_BUILD_ROOT
```

Better still, the `make_install` macro should do everything for you:

```
%install
%make_install
```

Comment: Stephen, Thank you for reply and help. I took out the path and macro is install it to /usr not the /local/usr/file1  Do you have any how I can fix this?